# Swift 3 closure property with closure as parameter causes segfault

Tags: parameters, properties, segmentation-fault, closures, swift3

The following property works:

```
var processData: ((NSDictionary, _: Bool) -> Void)?
```

But this property causes a segmentation fault:

```
var processData: ((NSDictionary, _: (()->Void)) -> Void)?
```

The second property was working fine in swift 2

**update**

here is an mcve

```
import UIKit

protocol SomeProtocol {}

class SomeClass<T: SomeProtocol>: Operation {
    var a: (((() -> Void)) -> Void)?
}
```

Each of the following (individually) stop the crash:

- remove inheritance of Operation or
- comment out the `var a` line or
- remove `<T: SomeProtocol>`

Comment: Could you please provide an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  The problem is likely in how you use that 2nd property.  I wrote a quick test program, and it did not segfault.

Comment: These two are completely different. For the first, the parameters of the closure is a dictionary and a boolean. For the second, they are a dictionary and another closure. And as OmniProg said, both are fine, and it's merely a question of how you're using them. BTW, the `_:` is not needed, e.g. `var processData: ((NSDictionary, ()->Void) -> Void)?` is sufficient.

Comment: Interesting. I'll try to make an mcve. I'm actually not using the property anywhere. If I comment the property out then the project builds and runs. and If I uncomment it I get a segfault. Thanks!

Comment: @OmniProg added an MCVE

Comment: OK, I see now, the segfault happens at build time, not at runtime.  Sorry, I thought it was at runtime.  I think you should file a bug report with Apple, this appears to be an Xcode bug.